# hide / disable accordion panels temporararily

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

**Need to know how to control expected behavior using JQuery UI Widget.**
I am using JQuery UI Accordion to implement multipart form/step-wise user interaction.
I want to hide / disable subsequent accordion panels until user completes some action in previous panels.

Can you please help me understand how to hide/disable accordion panels?

[sample code :](http://jsfiddle.net/mundie/eckZW/)

```
HTML
<div id="accordion">    
<h3><a href="#">Section 1</a></h3>
<div>
    <input type="button" value="Go to Section 2" id="button1" />
    <br/>
    <label>Section 2 can be visible/clickable only after clicking this button.</label>
</div>
    <h3><a href="#">Section 2</a></h3>
<div>
    <input type="button" value="Go to Section 3" id="button2" />
</div>
    <h3><a href="#">Section 3</a></h3>
<div>
    <input type="button" value="Go to Section 4" id="button3" />
</div>
    <h3><a href="#">Section 4</a></h3>
<div>
    <input type="button" value="Go to Section 1" id="button4" />
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(function () {
$("#accordion").accordion({
    autoHeight: true
});
$("#accordion").accordion({
    collapsible: true
});
$("#button1").on("click", function () {
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        active: 1
    });
});
$("#button2").on("click", function () {
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        active: 2
    });
});
$("#button3").on("click", function () {
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        active: 3
    });
});
$("#button4").on("click", function () {
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        active: 0
    });
})
```

});

Comment: Without a code sample not much help can be given.

Comment: Show your code, or a fiddle

Comment: thank you for reply, [link] http://jsfiddle.net/mundie/eckZW/

Comment: It seems I can use beforeActivate method of UI Widget but still like to know there is any way to completely hide inactive panels.

Answer (score 5):

#### [*Demo Fiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/D9a6V/)

```
$('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('disable')) {
        //If the tab is disabled, alert the user
        alert("Please complete the above details");
    }else{
        //Open the tab
        $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');
        $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');
    }
});
//Validate and enable/disable the next tab, currently only required validation is implemented
$('input').keyup(function(){
    if($(this).val()!=""){
        //Current textBox has value so enable the next
        $(this).parent().next('.accordion-toggle').removeClass('disable');
    }
    else{
        //Current textBox has no value so disable all the next
        $(this).parent().nextAll('.accordion-toggle').addClass('disable');
    }
});
```

*Not sure if you can achieve the desired functionality using jQuery UI Accordion.*

Comment: Not sure if I know all methods and properties of Accordion widget. Are these classes '.accordion-toggle' and ".accordion-content" added by widget code? I am looking for simple solution like 'enable:1', if it exists.

Comment: @Cipher The Accordion in the fiddle is not created using `jQuery UI Accordion widget`... The  `.accordion-toggle` and `.accordion-content` are not of the Accordion widget...

Comment: thanks for this. It behaves as expected. But I wanted to check if it can be controlled using methods of Widget. For e.g. as seen in this form [link](http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/multipart/)